# Doxygen log file entry relative paths

Tags: doxygen

I have a Doxygen project that outputs messages to a log file and we would like to commit the log file to version control as an easy way to spot when future changes improve or worsen the number of warnings.
The log file entries all show the full path of each file for each entry so each user's log files will be different on every line.
Is there a way to make the log file use relative paths for filenames as with the filenames in the generated output document?
Thanks

I have tried setting the Doxyfile entries to use relative file paths but it seems to have no effect on the log file content.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. With the log file you mean the file indicated by the setting `WARN_LOGFILE`. There is no feature for this in doxygen. I don't think it is a good idea to store this kind of information ion a repository, actually one should try to get rid of all the warnings as they indicate, potential, problems.

Comment: I'm using various versions from 1.9.1 to 1.9.8.
I generally agree that generated files are best not committed. I'm working on a big project with a lot of Doxygen warning which are not going to get fixed overnight. By committing the log file, users and the pipeline can check that no one is introducing new warnings while we work on reducing the existing ones.
This would be easier if the output messages were identical regardless of who ran Doxygen.

Comment: Best would be to postprocess the `WARN_LOGFILE` by means of stripping part of the path in the `WARN_LOGFILE` typically this would be, when using CMake, done in the `CMakeLists.txt` file and stripping the e.g. `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` part e.g. bu `sed` or by means of a python script. The result could be committed.